# Как убрать коммиты из pull request?

Tags: git, git-branch, pull-request

Подскажите пожалуйста, как выйти из следующей ситуации:
Работал я в ветке А - сделал 3 коммита и выполнил git push --set-upstream branch A, после этого находясь в этой же ветке сделал другую (для работы над другой задачей)- поработал в ней - сделал порядка 7 коммитов - выполнил git push --set-upstream branch B - сделал pull requests и, блин, в этот pull requests подтянулись коммиты из ветки A - как их убрать от туда?)

Comment: `git rebase --onto master A B` - если `master` это ветка от которой вы хотели породить `B`

Comment: А в какой ветке это выполнять, в ветке B?

Comment: Это не важно. Можно на любой

Answer (score 1):

В общем удалось решить проблему, следующим способом ( спасибо за подсказку Roman Konoval):

1. Переносим ветку B на master

- `git rebase --onto master A B`

2. Удаляем remote B (правда и PR при этом закрывается)

- `git push origin -d B`

3. Пушим обновлённую ветку B уже от мастера и только с необходимыми коммитами:

- `git push --set-upstream-to origin B`

Comment: Пункты 2 и 3 можно было объединить в `git push --force --set-upstream-to origin B`